# Reflecting a List<T>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm trying to make a model reflection tool. I have come a long way so far but now i'm stuck.

I have this

```
public static void RenderModelList(List<T> modelList)
{
   foreach (T model in modelList)
   {
      PropertyInfo[] properties = model.GetType().GetProperties();
      foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
      {
         object propValue = property.GetValue(model, null);
         //Check if the property is a collection and do recursion 
         if (propValue != null)
         {
            if (isCollection(propValue))
            {   
               //This only works for Lists of the same <T> 
               List<T> li = Convert.ChangeType(propValue, propValue.GetType()) as List<T>;
               if (li != null)
               {
                  if (li.Count > 0)
                  {
                     RenderModelList(li, loop);
                  }                                            
               }
               else
               {
                  //Its another type what to do?
                  // Create a List<> of unknown type??         
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My problem is that if I pass this method a `List<Persons>` and the Person has a property which is a `List<Cars>` - I can't use Convert.ChangeType - because this is not the T.

So how do I loop thrugh a "List" and get access to the properties of this object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that your method can be a lot more loosely typed:

```
public static void RenderModelList(IEnumerable list)
{
    foreach (object model in list)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you just need to cast to `IEnumerable`, not a specific sequence or list type.

Comment: Thank you Jon, this solved my problems and my code got a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your method should not rely on `T`. You can just use `IEnumerable` instead (not `IEnumerable<T>`, because it again depends on `T`). Note that every `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable`, so your method will work with them; however, other collections often implement `IEnumerable` as well. This may or may not be what you need.

If you choose the proposed way, your test `isCollection` will be like this:

```
IEnumerable propValueAsEnumerable = propValue as IEnumerable;
if (propValueAsEnumerable != null)
    RenderModelList(propValueAsEnumerable);
```

I would perhaps refactor your method into something like that:

```
IEnumerable<object> GetPropertyValuesFlat(object o)
{
    return o.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(pi => pi.GetValue(o, null))
            .Where(pv => pv != null)
            .SelectMany(pv => pv is IEnumerable<object> ?
                          (IEnumerable<object>)pv : new[] {pv});
}

//...
foreach (object p in GetPropertyValuesFlat(o))
    render(p);
```

(caution: not tested)

Edit: well, won't work as `SelectMany` doesn't understand non-generic `IEnumerable`. Changed it to work with `IEnumerable<object>`. At least, each `IEnumerable<T>` is an `IEnumerable<object>` with class T.

Comment: Thank you for this and i like the refactoring you did - as Jon also said, Ienumerable was the solutions to my problems.